# How to add circular rating chart in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Im trying to add color based on user input. I tried to use custom paint, but unable to add color as for rating visualization.

What I wanna achieve: User will select a number from dropdown and based on the selected value the gradient color will fill .
Is it possible just using custom paint?

[image]

What I tried, Using custom paint in flutter

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using  [spider_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/spider_chart/versions) and [flutter_radar_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_radar_chart) you can create this type of chart.

Here, I founded python code you can check this link. may solve your problem [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/web-circular-barplot-with-matplotlib)

Comment: yes!! yess!! i'm using the `flutter rader chart` to create the chart but unable to draw the  rating bar based on user input.  Hardcode value also will work for now.